# How to multiply matrices in the result of using chain rule in the backpropagation algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, backpropagation

I am trying to understand how backpropagation works mathematically, and want to implement it in python with numpy. I use a feedforward neural network with one hidden layer for my calculations, sigmoid as activation function, mean squared error as error function. This is the screenshot of the result of my calculations: [image: Screenshot] , and the problem is that there is a bunch of matrices, and i cannot multiply them out completely because they don't have same dimensions.
(In the screenshot L is the output layer, L-1 is hidden layer, L-2 is input layer, W is weight, E is error function, lowercase A is activations)

(In the code the first layer has 28*28 nodes, [because i am using MNIST database of 0-9 digits as training data], hidden layer is 15 nodes, output layer is 10 nodes).

```
# ho stands for hidden_output
# ih stands for input_hidden

def train(self, input_, target):
    self.input_ = input_
    self.output = self.feedforward(self.input_)

    # Derivative of error with respect to weight between output layer and hidden layer
    delta_ho = (self.output - target) * sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights_ho, self.hidden), True)) * self.hidden

    # Derivative of error with respect to weight between input layer and hidden layer
    delta_ih = (self.output - target) * sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights_ho, self.hidden), True)) * self.weights_ho * sigmoid(np.dot(self.weights_ih, self.input_), True) * self.input_

    # Adjust weights
    self.weights_ho -= delta_ho
    self.weights_ih -= delta_ih
```

At the `delta_ho = ...` line, the dimensions of the matrices are **(10x1 - 10x1) * (10x1) * (1x15)** so how do i compute this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a note from CS231 of Stanford: http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/.

For back-propagation with matrix/vectors, one thing to remember is that the gradient w.r.t. (with respect to) a variable (matrix or vector) always have the same shape as the variable.

For example, if the loss is `l`, there is a matrix multiplication operation in the calculation of loss: `C = A.dot(B)`. Let's suppose `A` has shape `(m, n)` and `B` has shape `(n, p)` (hence `C` has shape `(m, p)`). The gradient w.r.t. `C` is `dC`, which also has shape `(m, p)`. To obtain a matrix that has the shape as `A` using `dC` and `B`, we can only to `dC.dot(B.T)` which is the multiplication of two matrices of shape `(m, p)` and `(p, n)` to obtain `dA`, the gradient of the loss w.r.t. `A`. Similarly the gradient of the loss w.r.t. B is `dB = A.T.dot(dC)`.

For any added operation such as sigmoid you can chain them backwards as everywhere else.

Comment: How do you initialise `dC`? Is it the identity matrix, or zeros? ones?